# Skrollr & Z-index

Tags: javascript, z-index

I've got a bit of an issue with skrollr & z-index.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPlFV.png

I'm trying to have the picture at the top to go underneath the blog post.

I can't for the life of me work out why, no matter where/how I apply the z-index (I assume that's what I should be doing) the image ALWAYS sits above the post. 

I've tried everything I can think of, putting it inside divs, inside the css...

You can make it go underneath the blog post by putting the post in the skrollr div, but then I run into lots of issues with line height.

I've stripped all my failed z-index attempts out, so it should be 'conflict free' of my old, stupid code.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fb4C/ (not 100% sure that this is correctly done)

https://github.com/pxlprfct/Blog-SO-Question

```
<div id="skrollr-body">
        <div id="test" 
            data-0="top:0px;"
            data-1000="top: 400px;" >
           <img src="apple.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <article>
        <h1>
            Hi there helpful person!
        </h1>
        <p> 
            Hi there, I've been trying, and failing, to do what I thought was a reasonably simple thing.
        </p>
        <p>
            I just want the picture to stay where it is, (don't worry about the horrible aspect ratio and how it looks crushed, I'm fixing that after) and the 'blog', well the article to overlap it.
        </p>
        <p>
            I've been pratting around with z-index and have done pretty much everything I can think of, but the image still persists to scroll on top of the text (rather than underneath).
        </P>
        <p>
            I have tried a few sketchy things that worked, but didn't work well. I think i'm missing something mega obvious, anyways. Thanks for being awesome :)
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt earum eum recusandae accusantium porro facere vero nulla delectus. Adipisci, omnis velit molestias nemo expedita! Ad, enim similique placeat rerum. Libero.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, fuga eius ipsa alias repudiandae itaque neque totam veniam ut minus dignissimos eveniet dicta unde quos enim possimus optio nihil omnis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, magni est officia quis vitae veritatis doloribus laudantium corporis doloremque ratione ut ullam voluptatibus numquam quos optio voluptas veniam corrupti repellat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, provident, maxime beatae ea distinctio aperiam dicta ipsa soluta consequatur eius explicabo cumque possimus iure temporibus laudantium eveniet et ex placeat.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, quidem sint labore saepe explicabo aspernatur sunt vero quos minima nesciunt velit et debitis est accusantium eveniet dolorum sed quibusdam voluptate!
        </p>
    </article>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use a background image for the div?

Comment: @JeffreyBlake Large background images should generally be avoided as they often cause rendering and performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `position: fixed` and tweaking the `z-index` to `-1` does the trick. You also have to set the `top` and `left` to `0`, but that's secondary:

```
#test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/8fb4C/1/

Comment: After much fiddling, I've found that why I was having an issue - it was down to '<script type="text/javascript"> var s = skrollr.init();</script>' being added to the end of the html file, removing it, makes it work flawlessly. I have no idea why that'd cause issues/why it's there, but hey it's all fixed - thanks :)